# GeoServer: Combining multiple raster stores into one WMS layer

Tags: geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo, getmap

I would like to publish a `DTM` as WMS using GeoServer. For the visual part I have a *hill-shaded* version of the DTM and the original DTM contains the height as floating points (level above sea). Combining these two datasets I would like to create one WMS layer in which:

- `GetMap` returns the requested BBOX from the hill-shaded dataset.
- `GetFeatureInfo` returns the height at the specified point from the original DTM.

**Is this possible in GeoServer or are there alternatives which could solve this?**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's essential to use the same layer name; then one way that comes to mind is to use two geoservers, one which has a layer group (http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/data/layergroups.html) combining the hillshaded DTM + heights that serves your WMS (e.g. http://example.com/geoserver/wms, with the 2nd Geoserver serving up a feature of the same name on a WFS (e.g. http://example.com/geoserver/wfs).

Alternatively you could implement some url rewrite rules on your webserver ((e.g. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)) to achieve the same job on one server.

Comment: I guess this is not possible in the current version of GeoServer. I do think however it could be nice to be able to route the different kinds of requests. I would like to avoid URL rewrite rules, since that is more difficult to maintain.